# Stopping comment submission if fields aren't set

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

Firstly, I have the jQuery set up so the form doesn't submit: http://jsfiddle.net/FztLS/1/

Only it doesn't submit if the fields are set. I was wondering if anyone knew what was going wrong in the script.

I assumed that the `return false;` would only apply if the field was empty.

Also, how do I apply the class to every empty field, not just the first?

Lastly, is there a better way to include the radio box validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone that helped, but I ended up fixing my own problem: http://jsfiddle.net/yBmdx/20/

Turns out that starting from scratch, and setting up an `if($validForm)` was the best method.

Answer (score 0):

Update your `else` clause to:

```
else {
    $('#respond input, #respond textarea').removeClass('form_error');
    $('#commentform').submit();
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FztLS/5/

Answer (score 0):

The 'submit' event can only be bound to a form element, you're attempting to bind it to a section.

FYI, `$("section#respond")` is bad practice. You should never have more than one element with the same id per page, all sorts of things will go wrong. This will suffice: `$("#respond")`.

Comment: Yeah I realised later that I had bound it to the wrong element -.- and there is only one `#respond` I just add the element first so I can quickly reference it while in dev mode. But thank's for reminding me!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
if ($('input[name="rating"]:not(:checked)').val()) {
```

Since these are radio buttons there will **always** be unchecked ones so you always get a value and therefore return false.

Try this instead:

```
if($('input[name="rating"]:checked').length === 0) {
```

Which means "If no radio button is checked".